# How to deny all traffic from other kubernetes namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-networking

Hey it's been a while trying to block traffic from other namespaces and only access pods in same namespace, I looked over many threads but none work! What I tried so far is:

I created a globalnetworkpolicy using calico to allow egress traffic:

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all-egress
spec:
  egress:
  - action: Allow
    destination: {}
    source: {}
  order: 100
  selector: all()
  types:
  - Egress
```

1. created two namespaces:

```
kubectl create ns policy-demo1
kubectl create ns policy-demo2
```

2. applied following networkpolicy in each namespace to enable ingress only in each namespace:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all-ingress
  namespace: policy-demo1
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all-ingress
  namespace: policy-demo2
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

3. created in each namespace an nginx server and a busybox to test:

```
# for namespace: policy-demo1
kubectl create deployment --namespace=policy-demo1 nginx --image=nginx
kubectl expose --namespace=policy-demo1 deployment nginx --port=80
kubectl run --namespace=policy-demo1 access --rm -ti --image busybox /bin/sh

# did same for namespace policy-demo2
```

The `wget -q --timeout=5 nginx -O -` and `ping <IP_of_nginx_pod>` works as expected in same namespace. However when I ping nginx container that lives in `policy-demo1` from `policy-demo2` it works, which I don't want this behavior. Want to block traffic comming from different namespaces.

I tried another networkpolicy and added `namespaceSelector`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all-ingress
  namespace: policy-demo1
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
           name: policy-demo1 # added this label to policy-demo namespace
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

but pinging or doing `wget` from busybox image to nginx in the same namespace stopped working, what am I doing wrong please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the fact that in the `namespaceSelector`, you specified `policy-demo1` instead of `policy-demo2` ?

```yaml
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
           name: policy-demo1 # added this label to policy-demo namespace
```

instead of

```yaml
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
           name: policy-demo2 # added this label to policy-demo namespace
```

Comment: Thanks @ABWassim for your comments, I believe it was correct, but changed it as you suggested but the networkpolicy is not blocking traffic when accessing a pod in a different namespace :/

Answer (score 0):

You should address both ingress and egress in your NetworkPolicy to get the results you desire.

Here's all you need -
Create this NetworkPolicy in namespace policy-demo1:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: restrict-to-policy-demo1
  namespace: policy-demo1
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector: {}
```

Create this NetworkPolicy in namespace policy-demo2:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: restrict-to-policy-demo2
  namespace: policy-demo2
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector: {}
```

The pods in policy-demo1 can now only communicate with pods in policy-demo1. Same applies for pods in policy-demo2.

You can remove your GlobalNetworkPolicy and any other NetworkPolicy objects.

Comment: Thanks @hasouscsed for your answer, I tried your configuration but didn't work in our prod cluster, the access of nginx from busybox within same namespace stopped working too, but when I tried your conf in my local environment it worked, but accessing (using wget and ping) pods from a namespace to another still working rather then be blocked :/ which is the desired behavior.

Comment: Then I’d have to assume you might have some other policy in production. Try listing all policies. 

As per your local environment, was the ping still working in the two namespace you have defined above? The NP only applies to the namespace you have defined it for, and not all namespaces.

Comment: yes pinging the two namespaces was working in my local environment, I don't know why the policy seems not fully applied

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I've put this together based on examples from the doc and haven't had a chance to test yet, but in case this gets you on your way.
I have two policy examples you could try for the policy-demo1 namespace (and rinse repeat for the second namespace).
The first one is a simpler, namespace scoped calico network policy, but I'm still allowing access to kube-dns from that namespace.
The second example is a bit more specific with namespace selectors within the allow/deny rules for both ingress/egress.

The last policy is a [default deny](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/network-policy/get-started/kubernetes-default-deny), because by default kubernetes will allow traffic. If these don't work you could also try setting the policy action to log and see what you get. [More info on logging here](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/network-policy/get-started/calico-policy/calico-network-policy#generate-logs-for-specific-traffic).

Also note the order of the policies. Default deny is 2000 because you want that to be evaluated last.

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-policy-demo1
  namespace: policy-demo1
spec:
  order: 20
  ingress:
    - action: Allow
      protocol: TCP
  egress:
    - action: Allow
      protocol: UDP
      source: {}
      destination:
        selector: k8s-app == "kube-dns"
        ports:
          - "53"
    - action: Allow
      protocol: TCP
      source: {}
      destination:
        selector: k8s-app == "kube-dns"
        ports:
          - "53"
  types:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
---
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: policy-demo1-allow
  namespace: policy-demo1
spec:
  order: 25
  ingress:
    - action: Allow
      source:
        selector: projectcalico.org/namespace in  {'policy-demo1', 'kube-system', 'calico-system', 'calico-apiserver'}
      destination: {}
    - action: Deny
      source:
        selector: projectcalico.org/namespace not in  {'policy-demo1', 'kube-system', 'calico-system', 'calico-apiserver'}
      destination: {}
  egress:
    - action: Allow
      source: {}
      destination:
        selector: projectcalico.org/namespace in  {'policy-demo1', 'kube-system', 'calico-system', 'calico-apiserver'}
    - action: Deny
      source: {}
      destination:
        selector: projectcalico.org/namespace not in  {'policy-demo1', 'kube-system', 'calico-system', 'calico-apiserver'}
  types:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
---
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
spec:
  order: 2000
  selector: projectcalico.org/namespace not in  {'kube-system', 'calico-system', 'calico-apiserver'}
  types:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, the traffic wasn't blocked between namespaces. I tested the deny traffic policy in my local environment with k3d and calico and accessing nginx still working it supposed to be blocked! How to troubleshoot please?